# Function on column in dplyr mutate after group_by not giving correct grouped results

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm just starting to use dplyr and have been converting some of my plyr code over.  I love the new syntax, but I'm having trouble getting mutate() to apply a function on a column by group, e.g.:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

t1 <- ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), transform, qrt=cut2(wt, g=4))  
levels(t1$qrt)  # works: different quartiles for each group

t2 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(qrt=cut2(wt, g=4))  
levels(t2$qrt)   # doesn't work: uses only 4 quartiles from the first group
```

At first I thought that the second example was using the entire `wt` column instead of the `cyl` groups, but it actually appears to be using only the quartiles for the first group and assigning them to all the groups even when the `wt` falls outside the range.

Am I missing some syntax around the `wt` reference inside the function in mutate?  I can get the ddply version to work for functions like `sum()`, so is there something about `cut2()` that is causing the problem?

I've read quite a few posts on what could be similar issues and have tried running the dplyr version in a clean environment without ddply loaded, among other things.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code works for me using the [development version](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) of *dplyr*.

Comment: Yes, so it does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with the latest version of `dplyr`, `0.8.3`. The outputed data frame shows that each `cyl` has its own set of ranges and the min and max `wt` in each bin do not fall outside the stated range.

```
remove.packages("dplyr") # Unecessary but proves that this is the latest deployment version
install.packages("dplyr")

packageVersion("dplyr")

# [1] ‘0.8.3’

library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)

t2 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(qrt = cut2(wt, g=4))

t2 %>%
  group_by(cyl, qrt) %>%
  summarize(min = min(wt), max = max(wt)) %>%
  arrange(cyl, qrt)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#     cyl qrt           min   max
#   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4 [1.51,1.94)  1.51  1.84
# 2     4 [1.94,2.32)  1.94  2.2 
# 3     4 [2.32,3.15)  2.32  2.78
# 4     4 [3.15,3.19]  3.15  3.19
# 5     6 [2.62,2.88)  2.62  2.77
# 6     6 [2.88,3.44)  2.88  3.22
# 7     6 3.44         3.44  3.44
# 8     6 3.46         3.46  3.46
# 9     8 [3.17,3.57)  3.17  3.52
#10     8 [3.57,3.78)  3.57  3.73
#11     8 [3.78,5.25)  3.78  4.07
#12     8 [5.25,5.42]  5.25  5.42
```